# TRoleAuth TDSDataModule dont work

Tags: delphi, authentication, datasnap

`RoleAuth` makes your job and rejects other connection:

```
[TRoleAuth('ModuleAdmin')]
TAdmin = class(TBaseServerClass)
```

but this doesn't work. Why?

```
[TRoleAuth('ModuleAdmin')]
TDataModuleEmployee = class(TDSServerModule)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354812/delphi-datasnap-authorization-not-repecting-troleauth-attribute ? i.e. not having `DSAuth` in the uses clause for the interface of the module

Comment: uses
  WinApi.Windows, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Datasnap.DSServer, DSAuth,
  Data.FMTBcd, Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr, Datasnap.DSClientMetadata,Datasnap.DSReflect,DSService,
  Datasnap.Provider,Datasnap.DBClient,DBXCommon,DataSnap.DSCommonServer,Datasnap.DataBkr;

type
{$METHODINFO ON}
  TDataModuleEmployee = class(TDSServerModule)